# How to deploy Django website in cPanel?

Tags: python, django, hosting, cpanel

I am new to the world of website hosting, especially in cPanel platform. I have a website which is developed using Python language, which makes use of Django also. I have hosted this website in CPanel. But it doesn't seems to be working.

When I browse my website domain (www.def.com), it displays a web page with my title and other text contents. But it is not displaying any of the media contents (images or videos) and along with other text contents it displays some of my code also. This shows that only the static contents are thrown out and the other dynamic requests are not getting processed at the server.

I could know that by default, cPanel doesn't support Django. Using SSH, I have installed Django. But I am not sure how to configure the same. Would be good if I can get a step by step instructions on how to install and configure DJango in CPanel.

FYI, this is a shared web hosting server from GoDaddy and that too not a virtual Private server or doesn't have root access.

Comment: CPanel is just a configuration frontend. Typical ways for hosting Django (or other Python apps for that matter) are WSGI and FastCGI, start from checking if your web server supports any of them.

Comment: Just my opinion, but GoDaddy is a bear to work with when it comes to something like Django. Something like Heroku, Webfaction, or (my personal choice) Digital Ocean might seem daunting at first but be easier in the long run. With nothing but a Cpanel and no root access, you're in for a headache.

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate of a question from another user - or another account operated by you - posted on the same day. I am not sure what the value is of posting such similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this : https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7254/can-i-use-python-2-7-2-with-my-hosting-account

Answer to your question is :  `cPanel` and `Plesk` shared hosting accounts do not support `Python 2.7`. So, **Django** might not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide from Plesk developers on how to run Django in Plesk 12 http://devblog.plesk.com/2014/10/plesk-and-django/